How to customize y-axis ticks in percentage in multi-histograms?
I have to create histograms from samples with different sizes. I'd like to set the y-axis as percentage. For that, I'm using PercentFormatter. But I''m having a hard time to customize axis ticks.
Below is are examples:
EXAMPLE #1
```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
x = np.random.randn(1000,1)
y = np.random.randn(100, 1)
fig2, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.hist(x, n_bins)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(xmax=x.shape[0], decimals=0))
ax2.hist(y, n_bins)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(xmax=y.shape[0], decimals=0))
fig2.tight_layout()
plt.show()`
```

EXAMPLE #2
```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
np.random.seed(19680801)
n_bins = 10
fig, ax3 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
x_multi = [np.random.randn(n) for n in [10000, 5000, 2000]]
ax3.hist(x_multi, n_bins, histtype='bar')
ax3.set_title('different sample sizes')
ax3.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(decimals=0))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()`
```

In EXAMPLE #1 I am using sharey=True. Thus, I 'd expected the y-axis ticks be identical. But this is what I got:
EXAMPLE #1
In EXAMPLE #2 I'd expect the y-axis to be a percentage of each histogram (individually). But this is what I got:
enter image description here
